# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKAnnotationView", referenced from: ERROR

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

.framework/MapKit, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)
    Undefined symbols:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKAnnotationView", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref-to-MKAnnotationView in MapViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I am getting this error when building on my device even though I added the mapkit and corelocation frameworks. Does anyone know how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add the framework MapKit to your project.

Comment: i did, and i added it to my file too really weird... the same files work one their own but when i copy them to my project they fail only when  buiding on device